# Complete control of a user profile through Open Graph

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm attempting to design a program, in Python, to interact with facebook using my profile. I'd like to have my program be able to write to walls, send personal messages, like things, etc... using my profile.

I've created an app and written on my own wall. BUt i was only able to do that because i gave the app permission to write on my wall. When I try to write on someone else's wall, I'm not allowed because the user has not given the app permission.

How can I allow python to use my profile, and write to other's walls without them first agreeing to use an app?

Thanks,

Comment: Without them agreeing, it is not possible.

Comment: But can't I allow python to use MY profile? My PROFILE is able to write on other's walls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for a user, using an app, to write on someone else's wall.

If you have the 'stream_publish' permission, you can POST to

```
http://graph.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID/feed?message=SOME_MESSAGE&access_token=TOKEN
```

However, you must be careful not to spam people's walls or do this without the user's permission - see the platform policies https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ - as this will result in your app swiftly being disabled.

Comment: could you please go into some detail. I'm not sure how to do this with python. Also, it is not clear whether the user wall that I am posting to must first agree to give permissions to the app which is posting.

Comment: In pythion, just use your favourite HTTP client to make a POST to the URL above. No, the user your posting to does not need to have authed your app or given permissions - as the primary user has auth'd your app, and the primary user can write on their friends walls, your app can do that on behalf of the user too.

Remember you need the publish_stream persmission.

If you wanna try this out, use the Graph Explorer at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer